# Can you install an apk in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

Is there any way as a bookcase or a directory or a virtual machine to run applications and programs for Android in Ubuntu that also work in Ubuntu-touch to use Android application Whatsapp on a phone or tablet with Ubuntu-touch?

Or there is an alternative method to install an APK program in Ubuntu? After all, Android works with Linux, right?

Comment: Android uses pieces of the Linux kernel, iirc, not the whole thing. Its apps and frameworks (pretty much everything you see) run in a Java or C++ VM, depending on how they were written. They aren't "native."

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu Touch cannot (at the time of writing) run APK files, as they're meant for the Android architecture.

Now, this does not mean it's *completely* impossible, but someone would need to write a program similar to WINE (some kind of compatibility layer) to allow such things to happen. As of now, there are no (known) plans to do such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is no, you cannot run Android applications on an Ubuntu phone.

Long answer is that if you build a click package of the app, including the APK and all of the necessary parts of the Android VM, along with solving the integration problems, you could install an app and use it in fairly limited fashion, in that manner. It's very likely you would not be allowed to redistribute such apps in the store, however, and you could only side-load said applications, due to licensing of the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

The program would have to be adapted and packaged for the Ubuntu phone [You can start here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/)

Comment: Link is dead. Ubuntu phone page has been deleted